# Edit custom picklist field using python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am currently trying to edit a custom picklist which is a field in our Cases in salesforce.

Im using simple salesforce in Python but it seems like im not able to edit the picklist. I am able to read the current list using the .describe() function like this:

```py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(instance='instance.salesforce.com', session_id='')

caseObject = sf.Case.describe()['fields']
picklistObject = None
for field in caseObject:
    if field['name'] == "verursacht_durch_MA__c":
        picklistObject = field
```

The way I want to edit the list:

```
for entry in picklistObject ['picklistValues']:
        entry['label']="name"
sf.editPicklist(picklistObject )
```

But I want to edit this picklist and I dont know how.
Does anyone know how to update / edit this list?

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please formulate a question and provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @fulaphex please clarify what exactly I should change. For me it seems like I formulated my problem and made clear what I need help with

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work by itself. Try to provide a complete example. Also, you're saying that you want to modify the picklist, but you're not doing it.
Construct a snippet of code, that can be executed on it's own and describe what you expect it to do.

Comment: Edited my post, I hope its better now

Comment: Do you want to modify the returned object or do you want to modify the data on the server?

Comment: @fulaphex I want to modify the data on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to find a solution for this, see my answer here:
[Updating Picklist in Salesforce using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537360/updating-picklist-in-salesforce-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [docs](https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_salesforce.api.html?highlight=describe#simple_salesforce.api.SFType.describe) `describe()` returns you a dictionary decoded from the JSON. Modifying this dictionary won't modify the data on the server. It looks like you're interested in the [`update()`](https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_salesforce.api.html?highlight=update#simple_salesforce.api.SFType.update) function.

Comment: Sadly I cant access the "verursacht_durch_MA__c" field directly since its a field used in Case, which means I cant use the update function on it. I can update a Case with a Value from the "verursacht_durch_MA__c" list but I cant update the values inside the "verursacht_durch_MA__c" list like that